# How to properly migrate a sqlite3 database using the Sequelize.js ORM?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

It seems that `sequelize` is not connecting/opening the sqlite3 database file I have in the root directory of my project. The output from the `sequelize -m` command says that everything was migrated just fine, but the sqlite3 database file remains empty.

## config.json

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": null,
    "password": null,
    "database": "main",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "sqlite",
    "storage": "../data.sqlite3"
  }
}
```

## 20140814210910-createUsersTable.js (migration file)

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      }
    }).complete(done);
  },
  down: function (migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.dropTable('users').complete(done);
  }
};
```

## Terminal output

```
$ sequelize -m
Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
Running migrations...
20140814210910-createUsersTable.js
Completed in 18ms
```

## Folder Structure

```
|-.
   |-bin
   |-config
   |--config.json
   |-migrations
   |--20140814210910-createUsersTable.js
   |-node_modules
   |-server
   |-tests
   |-data.sqlite3
```

Comment: You may also want to check SQL-based migration solutions, e.g. [SQLite Client for Node.js Apps](https://github.com/kriasoft/node-sqlite)

Answer (score 5):

The error was the path value for `storage` in `config.json`.

Edited the `config.json` to read:

```
{
  "development": {
    "dialect": "sqlite",
    "storage": "data.sqlite3"
  }
}
```

and it worked.